# Why is it impossible to free xenografts from animal proteins or allografts from another person's proteins?

Tags: plastic-surgery, implant

I've heard that, for example, rhinoplasty surgeons try to use rib grafts or ear cartilage grafts from the person they're operating when they do surgeries, because donor grafts are not as good, since it is impossible to free them from foreign proteins and since there are always foreign proteins, there's always some form of inflammation.

Why is it impossible? Are there any publications regarding that? Thanks.